# GetThreadContext returns EBP = 0

Tags: c++, windows, threadcontext

I'm trying to get the value of another process' EBP register on  windows7 64 bits.
for this I'm using GetThreadContext like this:

```
static CONTEXT threadContext;
memset(&threadContext, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));
threadContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
bool contextOk = GetThreadContext(threadHandle, &threadContext);
```

The EIP value seems ok, but EBP = 0.
I tried using also WOW64_GetThreadContext but it didn't help...
GetLastError() returns 0 so it's supposed to be ok.
I do suspend this thread with SuspendThread and It DOESN'T happen every time I sample the thread.

What could cause this?

Comment: Do you know "You cannot get a valid context for a running thread. Use the `SuspendThread` function to suspend the thread before calling `GetThreadContext`."?  MSDN

Comment: Since you have the process (or at least the thread) suspended, maybe you could attach a real debugger to it and see what *it* says EBP is.

Comment: I just tried it but apperantly VS express cannot attach to a suspended or already debugged process :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause is that the register's value really is zero at the time you inspect it. It's a general-purpose register, so the program can set it to whatever value it wants.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to hold the start of the function?

Comment: On the x86, there are (essentially) two stack frame layouts: EBP frames and FPO frames. In an EBP frame, EBP points to the previous EBP, EBP+4 points to the return address, and EBP+8 points to the first stack passed argument. In an FPO frame, EBP isn't used as a "frame pointer" and instead is a general purpose register. So, it really depends on the target function.

Comment: But the project I read the thread context from is not using the "Omit Frame Pointer" optimization.

Comment: You have no idea exactly where you'll freeze the thread context.  It certainly isn't guaranteed to be executing code from that project.  Could just as well be Windows code.